# Pass data from one ViewController to another ViewController using NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I need to data from one ViewController to another ViewController 
Here I've Multiple Textfields in first ViewController then it will passed the SecondViewController in Whatever Data i entered in FirstViewController.
Can You Please suggest me.

Comment: maybe you should implement a proper _model-layer_ instead of using the _user defaults_ – because the _user defaults_ is not for transferring massive amount of data in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is for storing

```
NSString  *verifyStatus=@"Y";

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:verifyStatus forKey:@"verify_status"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

for retrieving

```
 NSString *verify_status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"verify_status"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use property for this...  Because It's easy ..

Make `NSMutableDictionary` type Property in  another `ViewController` and send from first ViewController

Make this type property in your second viewcontroller

```
  @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *textFieldDataDic;
```

and send data from first viewcontroller like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *textFieldData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [textFieldData setValue:textfield1 forKeyPath:@"textF1"];
 [textFieldData setValue:textfield2 forKeyPath:@"textF2"];

ViewController *secondView = [[ViewController alloc]init];
secondView.textFieldDataDic = textFieldData;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```