# Adding/Concatenating two textfields into one label in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, label

I have two text fields, say name and initial in one view controller and I want to display both as one label in another view controller. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you wants to display value of both textfield in Label??

Comment: Better to go through some tutorials for sending data from one page to another page it's quite easy but you are beginner so you need to learn some basic knowledge.

Comment: Your question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/898274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that this is your `first Viewcontroller`

this is your `UIButton` action for Navigating `secondVIewcontroller`

```
- (IBAction)btnSignUp_touchUpInside:(id)sender
{

SignUpViewController *vc=[[SignUpViewController alloc]init];  //addyour secondviewcontroller
 vc.strFromUnlinkPage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@",yourinitialtextfield.text,yournametextfirld.text];    // here we concatennating 2 strings
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

this is your `secondVIewcontroller.h` create the one `NSString` just like

```
 @interface SignUpViewController : BaseViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>{

}
 @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *strFromUnlinkPage;

 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblGuide;   //assumethat this is your secondviewcontroller `UIlabel` Name
```

in your **.m** `ViewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.lblGuide.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strFromUnlinkPage];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send data from one page to another have a look [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277264/pass-data-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller-using-nsuserdefaults/24277319#24277319) And to Adding/Concatenating two string you have two ways -

1. Use NSMutableString that has appendString method.
2. Save nsstring in NSArray and use componentsJoinedByString Method